# Need to pass an array in Java to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, playframework

I am using Play Framework 1.x.

Is there any way to pass an array from the controller to the template as a Javascript array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play will automatically map your parameters when you do a POST or GET from javascript to Java.  You can use the renderJSON method to pass an object from Java to javascript.  Then use something like jQuery to map it to an array.  Maybe if you give us some context we can help you a little more.

```
    public static void getContactsTable() {
    List<Contacts> contacts = Contacts.findAllOrderByInserted();
    renderJSON(contacts);
}
```

This is then mapped to a route.

```
 $.getJSON("@{ViewContacts.getContactsTable()}", function(data) {                  
        var series = { 
            data: []
        };    
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {            
            series.data.push([parseInt(item.date), item.qty]);                
        }); 

        options.series.push(series);

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

This is a small example of a highcharts chart I've done.

Here is another example of going the other way and then sending data back to be rendered on the page.

```
    public static void testing(List<Long> selected) {

    List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

    for (Long index : selected) {
        Contacts contact = contactService.findById(index);
        contacts.add(contact);
    }
    renderJSON(contacts);
}
```

This takes a javascript array.  As you see the mapping will automatically map it as a list just fine.  You could just as well have a java array though.

This is the javascript function.

```
       var template = 'selectedTemplate';
 var selectedOutput = '#selectedOutput';
        $.post('@{ViewContacts.testing()}',{ selected : selected }, function(data) {
                    $(selectedOutput).html(tmpl(template, { items:data }));  
                });

    <div id="selectedOutput">
        <script id="selectedTemplate" type="text/html">

            <% for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
            var item = items[i];
            %>

            <li><%= item.name %> - <%= item.email %></li>
            <% } %>  

        </script>
    </div>
```

As you can see this is an ajax request also.  I'm taking the selected data(which is just an array of selected nodes) then passing this into the function.  I then get back data (function(data)) and map that to the items array.  I'm using ejohn as the templating.

Answer (score 1):

You actually seem to make a confusion between server-side and client-side code

Your Java code runs on your server while your javascript code runs in the browser. You can't really 'pass' an array from Java to Javascript.

But your Javascript code can call your server to get values from your Java code (with AJAX, for example), or your Java code can write javascript code that declares an array variable wich then can be used by this javascript code along with the HTML in your views

Cheers

Grooveek